# AppEngine (JAVA): Updating record

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have the following code [in doPost()] to edit existing record. It does not give any error but record not saved. Any idea? or **what is best way to update exsting record based on a single unique field?**

```
     if(sAction.compareToIgnoreCase("S")==0)
     {

         String email = req.getParameter("Email");

         PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();             
         Query query = pm.newQuery(SMSUser.class);
         query.setFilter("Email == pEmail");
         query.declareParameters("String pEmail");
         List<SMSUser> users = (List<SMSUser>) query.execute(email);
         if(!users.isEmpty())
         {
            Iterator it = users.iterator();
            SMSUser u = (SMSUser) it.next();
            u.ContractPerson = req.getParameter("ContractPerson");
            u.Company = req.getParameter("Company");
            u.Address = req.getParameter("Address");
            u.Phone = req.getParameter("Phone");
            u.Aid = req.getParameter("Aid");
            u.Pin = req.getParameter("Pin");
            u.SenderId = req.getParameter("SenderId");
            u.Url = req.getParameter("Url");
            u.Operater = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("Operater"));

            pm.makePersistent(u);
        }
        return;
     }
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples to show how to add and delete but i could not find any for editing records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added getter/setter functions and it is working. Still wondering why???
However my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Persisting an element using directly the PersistenceManager requires you to close the persistance manager, as [the GAE doc clearly states](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Updating_an_Object).

Comment: after 
pm.makePersistent(u); 

i have added 

pm.close();

But it still does not work

Comment: can you hardcode an edit ,as in,
            u.Company = "a hardcoded blah company";
and test it? (just to eliminate any other logic errors)

i just fixed a similar issue with my app and pm.close() really did resolve it

Comment: When you say "it does not work", have you got any relevant logs, or is it simply that "nothing happens" ? What do you see when running your code in a debugger on the local datastore (in dev mode) ?